# Add to Table of Contents -- Changes font

Tags: table-of-contents

my problem is, when I suppress the numbering of a chapter but want to add it to the table of contents, Latex doesn't use the same font as it should use when I use \chapter{}.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman,titlepage=firstiscover,chapterentrydots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap*{Abstract}





\mainmatter
\chapter*{Remarks}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Remarks}

\chapter{Remarks}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not LaTeX but classicthesis and it seems to be by design. You can change it like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,ngerman,titlepage=firstiscover,chapterentrydots]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Abstract}   

\mainmatter
\chapter*{Remarks}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Remarks}

\chapter{Remarks}

\end{document}
```

Be aware that classicthesis uses titlesec and titletoc which are not compatible with and not supported by the KOMA-classes. Expect side-effects.